# updating each rows column to new column

Tags: php, mysql

I have many rows in my table. One of the columns is called `name`. I also have a new column called `blog_id`. I would like to make each `blog_id` like this:

```
$blog_id = strtolower(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^\wáéíóú]/', '-', $name)));
```

I have tried this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","foo","bar","blog");

$fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name
FROM entries");

foreach($fetch as $name2){

$id = strtolower(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^\wáéíóú]/', '-', $name2)));

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO entries (blog_id)
VALUES ('$id')");

}
mysqli_close($con);
```

But I get the error `strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make out what the error says? The part where it says that you gave it an array, when it expected the string? Then you go to php.net/preg_replace where it says `preg_replace() returns an array if the subject parameter is an array, or a string otherwise.`. Read carefully, it mentions **array**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach($fetch as $row){
    $id = strtolower(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^\wáéíóú]/', '-', $row['name'])));
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO entries (blog_id) VALUES ('$id')");
}
```

You're looping over each row, each row is an array of what you have selected in your query, in this case 'name', I guess you were expecting to loop over an array of names instead of rows with names.

**EDIT**

I would probably do it this way to be sure too:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)){
    $id = strtolower(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^\wáéíóú]/', '-', $row['name'])));
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO entries (blog_id) VALUES ('$id')");
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Instead of INSERTING the rows, you should UPDATE them.
In this case you should also get the id of the rows, so your SELECT code would be:

```
$fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, name FROM entries");
```

then you should do something like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)){
    $id = strtolower(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^\wáéíóú]/', '-', $row['name'])));
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE entries SET blog_id='".$id."' WHERE id=".$row['id']);
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I expected that you wanted to do that because of the INSERT statements in your code, I will update my answer for you.

Comment: I am getting th error: `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given` needs to be `mysqli_fetch_array` instead!

Comment: Sorry, it should've been `mysqli_fetch_array()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`. Updated!